# MongoDB shutdown fails with authentication turned on

Tags: mongodb, system-administration, database

Steps:

connect to mongo shell via localhost,

> use admin
>   switched to db admin
>   db.shutdownServer()
>   assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: unauthorized"
>   Error: Printing Stack Trace
>       at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
>       at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:6:5)
>       at assert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:14:5)
>       at DB.shutdownServer (src/mongo/shell/db.js:346:9)
>       at (shell):1:4
>   Tue Nov 12 23:05:45.236 assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: unauthorized" at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:7

Any suggestion would be great. This started happening after we turned on authentication. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you did not authenticate

instead of

```
mongo

use admin
```

try this :

```
mongo admin -u username -p password
```

and be sure there is a user on db.admin

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.addUser/

Comment: Excellent, I assumed logging in via localhost assumes admin privilege regardless of auth on or off, I was wrong... thanks